# Consume Third Party Service in MVC 4 Razor View in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, razor, view

I have MVC 4 project developed in visual studio 2013 ,and i also have data in third party service,like

**http://245.245.245.245/testapi/Service1.svc?wsdl**

How i integrate the Third Party Service in my MVC Controller and Display it on Razor Views(.cshtml).

Give Suggestion code or any examples...

Answer (score 0):

You can consume service by adding service reference in your web project. Its methods will be available and you will be able to call those methods within your web project.

If by some security reasons, you are unable to consume this directly, you can use HttpWebRequest:

```
 var address = new Uri("https://yourServiceAddress");
 var request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
 request.Method = "POST";
 request.ContentType = "application/json";

 //Your parameters that you need to pass
 var requestObject = new RequestJson()
 {
       userName = username,
       password = password
  };

  var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObject);
  var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestJson);
  request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

  using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
  {
        requestStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
  }

  using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
  {
       var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
       Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
   }
```

Comment: but i am using mvc controller class u are saying asp.net class

Comment: This doesn't matter whatever you are using. In your controller class, you can use the above code.

Comment: This is just a custom class. Create your class as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Using add web reference you can access the service functionalities

[image]

I hope the following post help you [Add Web Reference](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/add-web-reference-in-visual-studio-2010/)